# Null Value being returned in UITextVield

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

Using `Parse.com` as my backend, and attempting to load user data, but **running into an issue** where one of the fields is returning (null) initially, when no data is present by default. This is the only of the three using int as the datatype as opposed to string. The other two that attempt to load strings, which also don't exist by default, do not return (null) in the fields and are blank as expected.

Code (As you can see I try checking Parse.com with the if conditional and overwriting it locally if its (null), or at least I try to - then just have nothing display in `UITextField` rather then (null)) No luck!:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
    self.age = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", currentUser[@"age"]];
    if (self.age == nil ||  [self.age isEqual: @""])
    {

        self.age = @"0";
        NSLog(@"%@", self.age);
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"%@", self.age);
    }
    self.usersHomeTown.text = currentUser[@"hometown"];
    self.usersAge.text = self.age;
    self.usersName.text = currentUser[@"name"];

}
```

Comment: Try using `if (self.age.text.length)` instead since you're always creating a string.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you don't check if `currentUser[@"age"]` is `nil` or not. So you create the string from whatever it is. The resulting string will never be `nil`. You want:

```
PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
id age = currentUser[@"age"];
if (age) {
    self.age = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", age];
else {
    self.age = @"0";
}
```

I don't know if `current[@"age"]` returns `nil` or `[NSNull null]`. The above code assumes it returns `nil`. If it returns `[NSNull null]` then change the `if` statement to:

```
if (age == [NSNull null]) {
```

Comment: Seems to work initially, but if a user empties the UITextField and hits save, then goes back into the View for some reason 0 appears in the UITextField when I changed the else to say self.age = @""; , any ideas?

Comment: Since I have no idea what you do when "Save" is tapped, I no way to know but I can guess that you must be saving `0` for the user's age.